# What's the difference between "Thanks anyway" and "Thanks though"?

Tags: word-usage

To me, they seem to have almost  identicial meaning, but I believe there's a difference in usage. Could you please decribe the difference with specific examples?

Answer (score 12):

"Thanks" is a more casual way to say "thank you".

You say ["thanks anyway"](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/thanks-anyway) when you've asked someone for help, but they are unable to help you.

You say ["thanks, though"](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/thanks-though) when you refuse someone offering to help you because you don't need help.

These two may be used interchangeably, *though*.
From the context, the meaning would be understood, *anyway*.